# How do I locate dependencies for a dll?

Tags: devexpress

I have written a Dev Express winforms application. 
And I created a deployment file using [the Dev Express instructions](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AssemblyDeploymentTool/CustomDocument17237)

However when I deploy and run it I get the following errors

```
Exception occurs while activating the 'DevExpress.ExpressApp.SystemModule.ShowNavigationItemController' controller:
Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.ExpressApp.Xpo.v14.2, Version=14.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
Inner exception:   
Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.ExpressApp.Xpo.v14.2, Version=14.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The file DevExpress.Xpo.V14.2.dll is actually present.

How do I locate the real missing files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deploy the DevExpress.**ExpressApp**.Xpo.v14.2 assembly as well. Not only DevExpress.Xpo.v14.2.

Comment: what do you mean by the assembly? what files make it up?

Comment: ah the similar names DevExpress.ExpressApp.Xpo.v14.2  and DevExpress.Xpo.v14.2.
had me confused!